# How to take an url passed variable into another one?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to take an url passed variable to make another variable to pass it to a  sql query...

Page URL: ***somewhere.php?var1=blah&var2=blah!***

I want to do this:
***$var = $_GET['var1'];***
*$var2 = $_GET['var2'];*

*I can *echo* it but i want to make them a new variable.*

Any Suggestion?

Comment: And what is it about? You know how to extract values from `$_GET` - so what's the problem?

Comment: You've already made them new variables

Comment: I use $_GET['var'] but the value appear to be null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When use a "get" style url: eg. **somewhere.php?var1=blah&var2=blah!**

PHP stores the queries and adds them into a pre-defined $_GET array

When you say:

```
$var1 = $_GET['var1'];
```

You are assigning a new variable $var1 to the value of var1 from the $_GET array

Once you do this, you can pass it into an SQL query. Or, just pass $_GET['var1'] into the query.

Remember to escape the variable though!

```
if(isset($_GET))
{
    $var1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['var1']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table` VALUES(NULL, '{$var1}', '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['var2']) . "')");
}
```

I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

try this   $$var and $$var2 as new variable

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
$people['me'] = ‘robert’;
$people['friend'] = ‘sam’;
$people['girl'] = ‘bailey’;

foreach($people as $key => $val) {

$$key = $val;
}

So that

echo $me; //echo “robert”;
```